# Is this normal behavior for Yahoo PlaceFinder API? Seems odd to me

Tags: geolocation, yahoo-api

So I have this lat/lng pair, 39.905983/116.459373. Forever, the PlaceFinder API has been returning WOE ID 2151399 for this. Then suddenly it stopped, and started returning null (empty) instead.

I thought maybe the service was remembering that it had already done this for my API key, so I switched to another one. Still, null WOE ID. It makes sense because it is still processing other lat/lng pairs which I have also queried excessively during development.

I changed the values sent to the PlaceFinder query to 39.9059830001/116.4593730001 (just added 0001 to the end of each), and it started returning the WOE ID again.

My question: What gives?

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same query using PlaceFinder via the YQL Console:

[`select woeid from geo.placefinder where text="39.905983,116.459373" and gflags="R"`](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20woeid%20from%20geo.placefinder%20where%20text%3D%2239.905983%2C116.459373%22%20and%20gflags%3D%22R%22&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys)

...and get the same WOEID result you mentioned:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng"
    yahoo:count="1" yahoo:created="2012-03-20T16:24:40Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">
    <results>
        <Result>
            <woeid>2151399</woeid>
        </Result>
    </results>
</query>
```

I have not seen the behavior you mentioned, so I would consider it not normal. In the case where a null value is returned, do you have the normal HTTP status code? You might be running into a rate limit.

Comment: Thanks Brian for checking on this. If it was a rate limit, I would expect other queries to run into the same issue, but they aren't. Weird. I will check the http status and post an update.